# deploy Reporting Service 2008 to Reporting Service 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2008, downgrade

i work in Project already built on SQL SERVER 2005 and Reporting Service 2005, and i'am planing to upgrade my development environment to (SQL SERVER & RS) 2008,, but we have a lot of customer have to SQL Server 2005 and RS 2005. and when we test deploying Reports that have been upgraded to 2008 it's failed. is there anyway to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Can't deploy 2008 to 2005. Maybe someone has done some sort of transform from 2008 .rdl to 2005 .rdl. I doubt it though.

I just keep both RS 2005 and  RS 2008 installed and start/stop the services as I need them. I use BIDS 2005 for SSRS 2005 reports and VS2008 for SSRS 2008 reports.